# Check if a connected user matches the value of a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, fullcalendar

As part of a version of **FullCalendar** with user accounts, I would like to check if the current session matches the value of one of the fields of one or more events created via fullcalendar.
My events are generated as follows:

SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, description, organisateur, orgaavailable, donator, start, end, color FROM events ";
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();
```

My events are pre-generated via the following javascript function (which allows me to automatically replace the content of the fields of a form by the content of what has been retrieved from my database)

```
                eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                    element.bind('click', function() {
                        $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                        $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                        $('#ModalEdit #description').val(event.description);
                        $('#ModalEdit #organisateur').val(event.organisateur);
                        $('#ModalEdit #orgaavailable').val(event.orgaavailable);
                        $('#ModalEdit #donator').val(event.donator);
                        $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                        $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                    });
                },
```

Finally, my event is parsed in **JSON** via a **PHP** loop

```
                events: [
                <?php foreach($events as $event): 

                          $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                          $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                          if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                              $start = $start[0];
                          }else{
                              $start = $event['start'];
                          }
                          if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                              $end = $end[0];
                          }else{
                              $end = $event['end'];
                          }

                          $title = addslashes($event['title']);
                          $description = addslashes($event['description']);
                          $organisateur = addslashes($event['organisateur']);
                          $orgaavailable = addslashes($event['orgaavailable']);
                          $donator = addslashes($event['donator']);
                          if ($userlogged == $organisateur)
                          {
                              $vartest = 1;
                          }else{
                              $vartest = 0;
                          }
                ?>
                    {
                        id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                        title: '<?php echo $title; ?>',
                        test : '<?php echo $vartest; ?>',
                        description: "<?php echo $description; ?>",
                        organisateur: '<?php echo $organisateur; ?>',
                        orgaavailable: '<?php echo $orgaavailable; ?>',
                        donator: '<?php echo $donator; ?>',
                        start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                        end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                        color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                    },
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                ]
```

After that, my form is displayed in a modal and the fields are pre-filled with the information retrieved from my database (the form being too big, I don't know if I can put its code here)

The problem is that I can't see how I could compare the value of my session `($_SESSION['user_session'])` with the value of what is parse in the `"organisateur" value:` by the variable `$organisateur` to know if my connected user is the user indicated in `$organisateur`.

For information, I performed a test in my code that fills in the value 1 in the variable `$vartest` if `$userlogged == $organizer` (`$userlogged` being a variable retrieving the content of `$_SESSION['user_session'])` or the value `0` if the condition is not met.
The variable `$vartest` is then parsed next to the value `"test :"`

This condition works perfectly, `1` is displayed in the parse of the event belonging to the connected user and conversely, a `0` is displayed if it is not the case.
The parse is well formed when I look at the source code generated by my browser

Thanks in advance !

Comment: _“Finally, my event is parsed in JSON via a PHP loop”_ - that is _creating_ JSON, _parsing_ would be the opposite. // What your actual problem is now, not really sure. You got the check working for your `$vartest` variable, you say it contains the right thing, and outputs what you expect. So what exactly is missing now …?

Comment: Actually I want to change the display of my form (especially gray fields etc...) according to the value of $vartest
The problem I have is that my form is filled in according to what it is in the JSON, so a simple 'if' on the form does not work

Comment: So where does this happen, this “filling of the form”? Isn’t that what happens inside the click handler in the eventRender callback you have shown us? What would be stopping you from using if/else/whatever inside of that function?

Comment: In fact, "form filling" is done well during the EventRender.
But the display is done in a "template" after the EventRender.

This template is a form that fills in the values of its inputs using EventRender

(example for the "organizer" field) 
<input type="text" name="organisateur" class="form-control" id="organisateur">

And because this template is unique, I don't know how to modify its display according to the value of my variable (example: delete the "submit" button if my variable is equal to 1)

Comment: Something like `if (event.test == 1) $('#ModalEdit #submit').hide();` in eventRender would seem to make sense?